# Post to Rails from Emberjs using JSONAPI adapter, Rails not seeing the params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, active-model-serializers, json-api

I am trying to save a message model in Emberjs. I am using the JSONAPIAdapter and JSONAPISerilzier.

My post to rails hits the right controller and action as a post, but if I look inside with Pry, the data attributes are not there.
My payload:

```
{"data":{"attributes":{"body":"Why","user_id":"17"},"relationships":{"user":{"data":null},"conversation":{"data":null}},"type":"messages"}}

Content-Type:application/vnd.api+json
```

Rails params in the Rails console:

```
{"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/v1/messages", "action"=>"create"}
```

Answer (score 11):

So this may help someone else out.

You need to add support for the mime type for JSONAPI.

Add this to config/initializers/mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :json, %w( text/x-json application/jsonrequest application/vnd.api+json )
```