# JSONAPI strong params with Rails and Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember-data, strong-parameters

I'm using Ember with ember-data and a rails api. I had a createRecord() and save() for the record that was working fine. The payload in the network tab for the post request to create the record in rails looks like: `{data: {attributes: { foo: 'bar' } }`.

In the rails controller, I have strong params like so: `params.require(:data).require(:attributes).permit(:foo)`, which was working fine for a little while. Now when I send the request rails says that `param is missing or the value is empty: data`. If I look in the network tab in the browser the payload for the request still looks the same as stated above. If I `puts params` it only shows `{"controller": "api/v1/answers", "action": "create"}` and isn't showing the data payload at all.

Is there any reason why rails isn't picking up on the right params from ember now? I did try to add an association to the model that I'm trying to create, which is when it started failing. However, I rolled back to when it was working, but it's not working anymore.

Comment: Are you sure ember is sending params?

Comment: In the network tab in dev tools under the post request sent it shows the payload as `{data: {attributes: { foo: 'bar' } } }` so doesn't that mean it's getting sent correctly? Or is there something else to look for?

Comment: Hey, I do have the exact same problem. Ember showing some params in web inspector but not able to get them on Rails side... That just came up when I used last version of ActiveModel::Serializer with :json_api.

Comment: @le_Daf In the rails api I had forgotten to change the MIME types to accept application/vnd.api+json

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this by going into the `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file in the rails api and changing the file to look like:

```
api_mime_type = %W(
  application/vnd.api+json
  text/x-json
  application/json
)

Mime::Type.unregister :json
Mime::Type.register 'application/json', :json, api_mime_type
```

Comment: Thx a lot man! :) More info here https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1027#issuecomment-126543577. Also I am reading the params in controller like here https://github.com/Deovandski/Fakktion/blob/f152e9e3e99ee01146fcfc9277b38b7dda8026e7/app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller.rb#L39

Comment: With the latest version of AMS I don't think you need this initializer any longer. In your controller you can just do ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params) (ensure in config/wrap_parameters.rb you have enabled root elements)

Comment: I'm on ams 0.10.6 and I  still had to add this mime type configuration before I saw the params being sent to the controller at all. Of course, I still have to  use jsonapi_parse to parse the data.